# Double Integral to Polar Integral convert problem

Tags: definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I can't find the answer to this problem. It just says to find this double integral converting it to polar integral.

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{-{y}/{3}}^{{y}/{3}} \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\ dx\ dy$$

I know the first is $0$ to $π/2$ but I can't find the solution for the second:  $-y/3$ and $y/3$.

Comment: Use mathjax. [Click on this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0):

HINT:  Here is a graph of the lines $y = 1$ (blue), $x = -y/3$ (green), and $x = y/3$ (yellow):

[image]

Based on this graph, what is the range of $\theta$ values that you need to integrate over?  (It's not 0 to $\pi/2$.)  For a given $\theta$ value, what is the range of $r$ values you need to integrate over?

Comment: Im not good at this. Just trying to solve some exercises to get ready for the exams. So don't be hard on me... What Im thinking is that the θ value is from the y=0 line till the yellow line for the down value and till the green line for the up value?

Comment: @STUDENT_LIFE:  That's exactly correct.  The upper $r$ limit is a little trickier to figure out.  Remember that the blue line is the line $y = 1$, and try writing that in terms of $r$ and $\theta$.